# Description of initWithNibName, awakeFromNib and viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a good overview of `initWithNibName`, `awakeFromNib`, and `viewDidLoad` that lays out the best way to use each of these and describes exactly what each does?  I find these very confusing.  In the template that's generated with a View Controller, the comment about `initWithNibName` says:

> The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.

Except that this method never seems to be called (I'm using IB to set up the View Controller).  So should I use `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad` to initialize instead?

Comment: Is your question about iPhone or the Mac? It's one or the other; AppKit and UIKit are not interchangeable.

Comment: My question was about the iPhone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're creating your views in IB, then you should use `viewDidLoad`. That will be called every time the view is initialized to be put up. You use `initWithNibName`: when you're creating your view in code. You shouldn't use `awakeFromNib` with views for the iPhone.

The reason that `initWithNibName` is not seeming to be called is that interface builder actually creates a real instance of your view controller and then serializes that view. So, when you create the view controller in IB (add it to your project, basically), IB calls `initWithNibName`, but unless you have overridden the default `encodeWithCoder`:, any transient variables that you've set up there will be gone when the view is loaded from the nib (deserialized). This is generally okay since you usually want to set up your view with information specific to your applications current, running context rather than pre-determined initializers.

Even if you are programmatically creating views and view controllers, however, you can still put all the initialization in `viewDidLoad`. This is often better because if your view ends up getting cached (unloaded) and then brought back onto the screen, `viewDidLoad` can be called again while your initializer wouldn't necessarily be. For example, you create a view programmatically and push it onto a navigation controller's stack—later the view has been covered up and a memory warning is issued so the nav controller "unloads" your view but doesn't release the object—when the view comes back (other views get popped off), the nav controller will call `viewDidLoad` again so you can re-initialize, but `initWithNib` will not be called again. Note that this is a rare case and most people's applications will die horribly for other reasons at this point anyway, however.

Comment: Jason - 
Thank you - this is really helpful!  So follow up question: I am currently using awakeFromNib and viewWillAppear to do set up of my model (in awakeFromNib) and then use info from my model to set text in my view (in viewWillAppear).  If I move the code in awakeFromNib to viewDidLoad, is it guaranteed to run before viewWillAppear? I need to make sure the setup code is running before viewWillAppear.  I only want to set up the model once (obviously), so where's the best place to do that so that 1) it runs only once and 2) it runs before the viewWillAppear method?  

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will run before viewWillAppear. It will also run every time the view is loaded (like after a memory warning), making this the place to do these kinds of things.

Comment: Be careful putting one time init code in viewWillAppear because it gets called every time the view will become visible.  So if you navigate or push another view controller, when they return to the parent view controller viewWillAppear is called again.

Comment: justme's answer is much more on the ball than the above answer.

Comment: "If you're creating your views in IB, then you should use viewDidLoad"  Keep in mind, if you are not using a UIViewController, then viewDidLoad won't get called.  In other words, if you are creating views that you will be handling yourself, without the aid of a UIViewController, then you will never get a viewDidLoad call.  Nor a viewWillAppear, viewWill....

Comment: @occulus: justme's answer came an entire year later and a full version of the SKD later. When I actually wrote this answer, awakeFromNib absolutely did not get called consistently and almost rarely. Since 3.1, however, it gets called consistently the same as Mac OS X... so please, look at the dates and know the status of the SDK when I answer vs. somebody else.

Comment: If one is not using IB, shouldn't the init code go in loadView?

Comment: this answer seems wrong :( loadView should be used for non-interfacebuilder views, initwithnib is used when you want to initialize a view controller when its view was created in IB, viewDidLoad used to do work after the view is loaded(either from IB or loadView)

Answer (score 35):

I just finished doing some research on this topic so I thought I'd share a few of the things I learned.

1. There's nothing wrong with using `awakeFromNib` with views for the iPhone. See [this Apple Dev document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html).
2. `initWithCoder` is *not* a good place to do initialization when the view is loaded from a NIB file because other items in the same NIB file may or may not have been initialized at that point.  So an outlet might still be nil, for example. All items in the *same NIB file* are guaranteed to be initialized properly when `awakeFromNib` is called.
3. `viewDidLoad` *is* a good place to do setup work in the viewController.

So why would one want to use `awakeFromNib` in the view?  One reason I can think of is if you have stuff you want to do after the view has been initialized and hooked up to the other objects in the NIB file, but you want to encapsulate it in the view only. This reduces linkage with the view controller.

Comment: Another reason to use awakeFromNib is if you use views or subclasses like controls and buttons, without a UIViewController.

Comment: Some IBOutlet are still null when go to awakeFromNib in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895262/why-need-awakefromnib

Comment: but for UIView subclass ?

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad can get called more than once so it is not an appropriate place for most initialization (although in practice it's called just once unless you are meddling) - that is why awakeFromNib is special and very necessary: it only gets called once.

viewDidLoad doesn't exist on UIView - UIView has awakeFromNib for initialization and there are no other sensible options.

For the past six months I have been happily using awakeFromNib with storyboards (a single storyboard for an app) without any trouble at all and it has behaved perfectly with all outlets configured as specified in the documentation. Then today I took some code apart and put in a new view controller and views and none of it is working as I have experienced in the past i.e. all outlets nil in awakeFromNib. My theory is simple - the SDK sucks because it's very easy to do something trivial somewhere in your chain of controllers/views and classes and break everything.

Now I'm off to research this pointless topic, yet again, when all I need is a simple consistent place to do initialization.