# What method is called when a UITableViewCell is initialized by Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell and I need to initialize some ivars before it is displayed in a UITableView. I overrode `- (void)init` but that did not seem to be the designated initializer. Where should I be putting my code?

EDIT: the cell was made using UITableViewCell prototypes in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
```

Also, for what it sounds like you are wanting to do, you may instead want to override:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib;
```

Comment: to be clear: awakeFromNib is best if you need to be sure that the entire view is loaded from the xib/storyboard (ie if you're referencing anything via an _outlet_ property). initWithCoder is will work if you're only initializing your own ivars and don't care about the state of the control or outlets. See the top-rated-but-not-selected answer from @justme here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240010/description-of-initwithnibname-awakefromnib-and-viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

[– initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/initWithStyle%3areuseIdentifier%3a) is UITableVIewCell's designated initializer

Comment: I overrode it and inserted an NSLog, but it does no appear to be called.

Comment: The statement is technically correct inasmuch as this is the classes designated initializer so the _init_ in the original question was always wrong. It doesn't get called because the cell is defined in IB rather than purely in code, so IB initializes it. So it only became wrong when you added your Edit.