# UITableView using ECSlidingViewController not Populating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to populate the menu in ECSlidingViewController(a UITableVIEW) using the code below, but when I run the app the menu, or uitableview, is blank and not populated with the 3 MenuItems; Important, Invitation, and Agenda. I suspect the problem lies within didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but I'm not sure. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;

@end

@implementation MenuViewController
@synthesize menuItems;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Important", @"Invitation", @"Agenda", nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    return self.menuItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
}
```

Comment: If you put NSLog(@"%@", self.menuItems); in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, what does it print?

Comment: I feel quite certain that your array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Be sure to connect datasource and delegate outlets in IB, and

2) Is MenuViewController a subclass of UITableViewController?  If not, then I think you're going to need to load the table data yourself someplace.  Try this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];      // need to have an outlet named this
}
```

If you don't have an outlet setup called tableView, pointing to the table view, create one in IB.

Comment: I got it! It was just a rookie mistake. Forgot to connect the dataSource and delegate back to the viewcontroller. *Palm on face* This answer made me think to double check my outlets though so thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I'll edit so the answer will be clearer to the next person.  BTW, I think I've added hundreds of tables to view controllers in IB, and I _still_ forget to connect the datasource and delegate most of the time.  Then I see the blank table, and palm on face for me - so I should have guessed that first.  (you do also need the reload, I think)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your menuItems array is empty. Try populating it in viewDidLoad.

You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240010/description-of-initwithnibname-awakefromnib-and-viewdidload) for a discussion of awakeFromNib, viewDidLoad, initWithNibName.